# Multiplying and Adding Values across Rows

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have this data frame:

```
color <- c("AKZ", "ZZA", "KAK")    
color_1 <- sample(color, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.3, 0.3))
id = 1:100

sample_data = data.frame(id, color_1)


 id color_1
1  1     KAK
2  2     AKZ
3  3     KAK
4  4     KAK
5  5     AKZ
6  6     ZZA
```

Suppose there is a legend:

- K = 3
- A = 4
- Z = 6

I want to add two columns to the above data frame:

- sample_data$add_score : e.g. KAK = K + A + K = 3 + 4 + 3 = 10
- sample_data$multiply_score : e.g. KAK = K * A * K = 3 * 4 * 3 = 36

I thought of solving the problem like this:

```
sample_data$first = substr(color_1,1,1)
sample_data$second = substr(color_1,2,2)
sample_data$third = substr(color_1,3,3)

sample_data$first_score = ifelse(sample_data$first == "K", 3, ifelse(sample_data$first == "A", 4, 6))
 
sample_data$second_score = ifelse(sample_data$second == "K", 3, ifelse(sample_data$second == "A", 4, 6))

sample_data$third_score = ifelse(sample_data$third == "K", 3, ifelse(sample_data$third == "A", 4, 6))

sample_data$add_score = sample_data$first_score + sample_data$second_score + sample_data$third_score

sample_data$multiply_score = sample_data$first_score * sample_data$second_score * sample_data$third_score
```

But I think this way would take a long time if the length of "color_1" was longer. Given a scoring legend, is there a faster way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: In what format is the legend data, named vector, data.frame, other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option using `tidyverse`. I use `recode` from `dplyr` to change the letters to numbers according to the `legend`.

```
library(tidyverse)

legend <- c(K = 3, A = 4, Z = 6)

sample_data %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(code = list(recode(str_split(color_1, "", simplify = T), !!!legend)),
         add_score = sum(code),
         multiply_score = prod(code)) %>%
  select(-code)
```

**Output**

```
      id color_1 add_score multiply_score
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1 AKZ            13             72
 2     2 AKZ            13             72
 3     3 KAK            10             36
 4     4 KAK            10             36
 5     5 AKZ            13             72
 6     6 AKZ            13             72
 7     7 KAK            10             36
 8     8 AKZ            13             72
 9     9 AKZ            13             72
10    10 AKZ            13             72
# … with 90 more rows
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(103)
color <- c("AKZ", "ZZA", "KAK")    
color_1 <- sample(color, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.3, 0.3))
id = 1:100

sample_data = data.frame(id, color_1)
```

**Benchmark**

It looks like Rui Barradas' solution is the fastest of the answers so far.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. Your solution is slowest because you are using `scan` twice, can't you replace them with `code = as.numeric(paste0(.))`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks. I was able to cut out `scan`, which did speed it up, but had to put into a `list`. I tried converting just using `as.numeric`, but `mutate` didn't like that I was trying to return a numeric vector of length 3, when it expected 1. At least, it is much less verbose now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way.
The main trick is to `strsplit` into single characters and match these vectors with the legend. Then add or multiply the matching numbers.

```r
set.seed(2022)
color <- c("AKZ", "ZZA", "KAK")    
color_1 <- sample(color, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.3, 0.3))
id <- 1:100

sample_data = data.frame(id, color_1)

legend <- setNames(c(3, 4, 6), c("K", "A", "Z"))

add_mul <- function(x, l){
  add <- function(y, l){
    i <- match(y, names(l))
    sum(l[i])
  }
  mul <- function(y, l){
    i <- match(y, names(l))
    prod(l[i])
  }
  
  s <- strsplit(x, "")
  add_score <- sapply(s, add, l = l)
  mul_score <- sapply(s, mul, l = l)
  data.frame(add_score, mul_score)
}

sample_data <- cbind(sample_data, add_mul(sample_data$color_1, legend))
head(sample_data)
#>   id color_1 add_score mul_score
#> 1  1     ZZA        16       144
#> 2  2     KAK        10        36
#> 3  3     AKZ        13        72
#> 4  4     KAK        10        36
#> 5  5     AKZ        13        72
#> 6  6     KAK        10        36
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We can use `stri_replace_all_regex` to replace your `color_1` into integers together with the arithmetic operator.

Here I've stored your values into a vector `color_1_convert`. We can use this as the input in `stri_replace_all_regex` for better management of the values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

color_1_convert <- c("K" = "3", "A" = "4", "Z" = "6")

sample_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(add_score = eval(parse(text = gsub("\\+$", "", stri_replace_all_regex(color_1, names(color_1_convert), paste0(color_1_convert, "+"), vectorize_all = F)))),
         multiply_score = eval(parse(text = gsub("\\*$", "", stri_replace_all_regex(color_1, names(color_1_convert), paste0(color_1_convert, "*"), vectorize_all = F)))))

# A tibble: 100 × 4
# Groups:   id [100]
      id color_1 add_score multiply_score
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1 KAK            10             36
 2     2 ZZA            16            144
 3     3 AKZ            13             72
 4     4 ZZA            16            144
 5     5 AKZ            13             72
 6     6 AKZ            13             72
 7     7 AKZ            13             72
 8     8 KAK            10             36
 9     9 ZZA            16            144
10    10 AKZ            13             72
# … with 90 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an approach based on `tidyr::separate_rows()` followed by a grouped `dplyr::summarize()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

legend <- c(K = 3, A = 4, Z = 6)

sample_data %>%
  mutate(decoded = color_1) %>%
  separate_rows(decoded, sep = "(?!^)") %>%
  mutate(decoded = legend[decoded]) %>%
  group_by(id, color_1) %>%
  summarize(
    add_score = sum(decoded),
    multiply_score = prod(decoded), 
    .groups = "drop"
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 4
      id color_1 add_score multiply_score
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1 AKZ            13             72
 2     2 AKZ            13             72
 3     3 KAK            10             36
 4     4 ZZA            16            144
 5     5 AKZ            13             72
 6     6 ZZA            16            144
 7     7 ZZA            16            144
 8     8 KAK            10             36
 9     9 KAK            10             36
10    10 AKZ            13             72
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative, using some libraries optimized for speed, `stringi` for string manipulation and `Rfast` for matrix operations. Note that when any `NA` values are present in your data `matrixStats` is safer to use than Rfast.

```
set.seed(2022)
color <- c("AKZ", "ZZA", "KAK")    
color_1 <- sample(color, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.3, 0.3))
id = 1:100
sample_data = data.frame(id, color_1)

m <- strsplit(sample_data[["color_1"]], "") |>
  unlist(use.names = F) |>
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(
    c("K", "A", "Z"),
    c("3", "4", "6"), vectorize_all = F) |>
  as.integer() |>
  matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T)
sample_data$add_score <- Rfast::rowsums(m)
sample_data$mul_score <- Rfast::rowprods(m)

head(sample_data)
  id color_1 add_score mul_score
1  1     ZZA        16       144
2  2     KAK        10        36
3  3     AKZ        13        72
4  4     KAK        10        36
5  5     AKZ        13        72
6  6     KAK        10        36
```